# Section numbering style changes when Part I is made Roman

Tags: sectioning, page-numbering

I am writing a book and wish to make the numbering in part I Roman while preserving the numbering style in the Arabic part II. I present as a minimal example below. If the "\renewcommand"s are commented out the numbering is as desired. After Part I is given Roman numbering the wished for nesting disappears. How can I preserve the original format?

```
    \documentclass[10pt,oneside,usenames,dvipsnames]{book} 
      \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
    
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
    \renewcommand {\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
    \renewcommand {\thesubsection}{\Roman{subsection}}
    
    \part{1}
    \chapter{FIRST}
    \section{First}
    \subsection{first}
    
    
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
    \renewcommand {\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand {\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
    \part{2}
    \chapter{SECOND}
    \section{Second}
    Want this numbered as 2.1 which it is until Part I numbering is made Roman. It then appears as just 1. The section numbering style is not as wanted after a Roman Part I.
    \subsection{second}
    Want Numbering here to be 2.1.1 which it is until Part I numbering is made Roman. It appears as 1. The subsection is numbered but the style is wrong. How can I keep the 2.1.1 style of numbering with a Roman Part I?
    
    \subsubsection{2nd}
    
    Want no numbering here, which works with and without the Roman Part 1.
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesting can be acheived by including the parent section and a full stop in front of your renewed commands as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand {\thesection}{\Roman{chapter}.\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand {\thesubsection}{\Roman{section}.\Roman{subsection}}
```

(and similarly when you introduce the arabic numbers)